# Introduction tutorial/s for web accessibility?

Tags: accessibility

I've ignored this topic for really long time and I would like to get at least basic instincts on this subject (You know - more than "don't forget to add `alt` on images").

Assuming that I'm complete noob on this, where should i look first?

---

Please, do **not** just post some ISO standards, html spec or whatnot. That will just recoil any interest.

I'm looking for gentle push with guidelines where to look next.

P.s. I did try to find duplicate question/s w/o any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as your question is after guidelines the WCAG might help you.

Web Content Accessibility Guidelines has some details about making your site ready for different media which disabled people might use to access web content.

It also covers somewhat more than your alt tag stuff and related.  Not sure where in the world you are but I've heard the USA have made it law but I'm not def on that as I'm in London.

At the risk of reaping your wrath, have a look at w3.org/TR/WCAG. It's not ISO, and its useful really as a general guide.